# symfony 2.8: id AND uid column in same table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I require two unique fields in my `mysql` table `id` & `uid`:

- the `id` is of course an `auto increment` field as `integer`
- the `uid` field is an `GUID` `string` field.

Both fields are required and are working in other solutions well, so no way around it.

How can I bring symfony v2.8 with an ORM to use and auto fill both fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@ORM\GeneratedValue` annotation only works in conjunction with `@ORM\Id`. In any other case it is just ignored.

Fortunately you do not need the database to make a UUID. So just do it in the constructor of the entity and you are fine:

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->uid = generateUuid();
}
```

There is plenty of documentation out there on how to generate a UUID.

Comment: thanks. that's the solution, but i can check your answer in 7 minutes as solution. currently i get a red blocking message.